# display JSON on an html table using vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, html, json, rest, client

i'm using vanilla js to send client request to a REST web service i designed. my GET method returns a list of books (List) in json format:

```
0: {name: "To Pimp a Butterfly", isbn: "ACBCDDSA", availableCopies: 10}
1: {name: "Stay with me", isbn: "SADDKHFLAHA", availableCopies: 15}
2: {name: "Foreign Gods", isbn: "AUZIBILLAH", availableCopies: 5}
```

i have a html table i would like to populate with these values. 
i am new to JS and i only just picked it because of the front-end i needed to tidy up. if someone could kindly point in a direction as to how i could go about this. here's a block of code, i tried to do, but it doesn't get it working.

i get an error. Uncaught TypeError: response.value is not a function
    at XMLHttpRequest.request.onload (book.js:103)

```
function getBooks() {
 const request = new XMLHttpRequest();
 request.open("GET", "rpc/manager/books");
 request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
 request.send();
 request.onload = (e) => {
   if(request.readyState === 4 && request.status === 200) {
      const response = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
      console.log(response);

    if(response === null) {
       alert("no book found");
       return false;
    }
    const table = document.getElementById("bookTable");
    const row = table.insertRow(1);

    const name = row.insertCell(0);
    const isbn = row.insertCell(1);
    const availableCopies = row.insertCell(2);

    for(var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
      name.innerHTML = response.valueOf(i).name;
      isbn.innerHTML = response.valueOf(i).isbn;
      availableCopies.innerHTML = response.valueOf(i).availableCopies;
    }
   }
 }
}
```

this is also my html table.

```
<table id="bookTable" align="center" border="1">
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Isbn</th>
        <th>Available Copies</th>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I'd be glad if someone could help, thanks.

Comment: Your "json format" is not valid JSON.

Comment: actually, my endpoint returns a java.util.List<Books> when i parse the response using JSON.parse(request.responseText); and logged it in the console that's what i get.  @RobG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The loop is just replacing the content of the same set of cells, presumably you want to create a new row for each book.

You aren't showing the actual JSON you get, so I suppose it's an array of book objects like:

```
[{"name": "To Pimp a Butterfly", "isbn": "ACBCDDSA", "availableCopies": 10},
 {"name": "Stay with me", "isbn": "SADDKHFLAHA", "availableCopies": 15},
 {"name": "Foreign Gods", "isbn": "AUZIBILLAH", "availableCopies": 5}]
```

You can also simplify the code. By default, the *insert* methods insert at the end of the set of rows or cells.

```js
var response = [{"name": "To Pimp a Butterfly", "isbn": "ACBCDDSA", "availableCopies": 10},
     {"name": "Stay with me", "isbn": "SADDKHFLAHA", "availableCopies": 15},
     {"name": "Foreign Gods", "isbn": "AUZIBILLAH", "availableCopies": 5}];

let table = document.getElementById("bookTable");
let row, cell;

for (let i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
  row = table.insertRow();
  cell = row.insertCell();
  cell.textContent = response[i].name;
  cell = row.insertCell();
  cell.textContent = response[i].isbn;
  cell = row.insertCell();
  cell.textContent = response[i].availableCopies;
}
```

```html
<table id="bookTable">
  <tr><th>Name<th>ISBN<th>Copies
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks rob. would you be nice to give me a hint as to why you used the keyword let when declaring the variables, other than var? thanks. @RobG

Comment: @olatunjioniyide—because I like to be hip? ;-) No real reason, you can use *var* for everything without issues so really it's a toss up for me. I think *const* should only be used for genuine constants (like `cost PI = Math.PI`), not just for everything that will only be assigned a value once (which probably covers about 90% of variables).

Answer (score 0):

To help with your current error, you'll want to use square bracket notation to index into your response array. Change your for loop to...

```
for(var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
  name.innerHTML = response[i].name;
  isbn.innerHTML = response[i].isbn;
  availableCopies.innerHTML = response[i].availableCopies;
}
```

Comment: Hey @Ben i implemented this. it populates the table with the last item in the array. thanks for the response. maybe i'd be able to work something out from here.